# How to add my (already working) javascript code to my Wordpress page?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a working JS code that is working as expected on my machine. This is a simple math quiz.

How can I implement this on one of my pages on my website which uses Wordpress.

thanks so much!

Comment: If you could get us a snippet of the JS and more details of how you implemented it into WordPress, folks could give you more detailed answers.
Right now, I don't know if your JS contains a syntax error or an expectation of a variable that doesn't exist, and that could be causing it. Or how you're embedding it might be causing it. It's hard to tell from this level of detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a small plugin or add your functions to the custom js file or create new js file in your theme and link it in  tag .